# Mongoexport remove ellipsis

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am trying to export data from MongoDB using this query..

```
mongoexport -d dbName -c myCollection -f title,meta,contents --csv -o test_export.csv
```

the problem is,when I open the generated csv file, the content field data has ellipsis and doesn't get the exact content, how can I able to remove this ellipsis and get the exact data content?

Comment: What tool do you use to open csv file?

Comment: I have the same issue, the outputted file has all the long lines with ellipsis. This is not a function of the editor used to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been [solved in version 2.0.7](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/pull/260) and above